# import conda package list to (default env)

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have exported the package list using command

```
conda list --export > packagelist.txt
```

Since no environment name is specified, I supposed to just export the package name of the default environment (Am I right?)
Then I want to import the package list to a new laptop and install this list of packages again, similarly, in the default environment

But I have googled the relevant answer, but majority of them are intended to create a new environment, like

```
conda create -n myenv2 --file myenv2.txt python=2
```

which is not what I plan to do. which command should I choose to import the package list to default environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

As you mentioned, you can do:

```
conda list --export > packagelist.txt
```

And then if you want to install that in your default environment (instead of creating a new one) you can just do:

```
conda install --file packagelist.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Export of environments packages:

```
conda list --name <env> --explicit > packageslist.txt
```

Import of packages:

- To use the spec file to create an identical environment on the same machine or another machine:

```
conda create --name myenv --file packageslist.txt
```

- To use the spec file to install its listed packages into an existing environment:

```
conda install --name myenv --file packageslist.txt
```

Source : https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html